# How do I retrieve column headings while converting my dataset into a list?

Tags: c#, sql, database, model-view-controller, model

This is my program where I am retrieving data from my dataset into a list.
Somehow, the column headings aren't coming with the data. How do I do that?

```
{
  var lresults = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                            select new executedModelResults
                            {
                                lsCol = getCol(rows, liColCount)
                            }).ToList();

            return lresults;
        }

        public string[] getCol(DataRow row, int liColCount)
        {
            DataColumn c = new DataColumn();
            string[] lsCol = new string[liColCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < liColCount; i++)
            {
                lsCol[i] = row[i].ToString();
            }
            return lsCol;

        }
```

lsCol[] is my string array that I'm using in my model to store the columns because they are dynamically laoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics. Create a class that's properties map to your column headers. For example if it was Products you were returning then the class might contain properties like Price, Name etc which would map to DB table fields called Price and Name.

Return your data as List which would be strongly typed and then access each record like

```
List<Product> lstProduct = new List<Product>();

    foreach(Product p in lstProducts)
    {
      p.Name
      p.Price
      ...etc
    }
```